# XPath for Descriptor in Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, workday-api

I'm trying to set properties and confused as to what the xpath would be.  For example, one of my properties is

```
props['SuperiorOrganization'] = parts[0].xpath('/rs:Report_Entry/rs:SuperiorOrganization/Descriptor')
```

and I tried using `rs:/descriptor` with no value.

My **xml** is returning something like this:

```
<wd:SuperiorOrganization wd:Descriptor="Name of Supervisory">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">XXXXXX</wd:ID>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rs:Descriptor` is an attribute and attributes have to be prefixed with an `@` in XPath expressions. So a working expression to get the string

> Name of Supervisory

could be

```
/rs:Report_Entry/rs:SuperiorOrganization/@rs:Descriptor
```

(Assuming that the `rs:` and the `wd:` namespaces are interchangeable.)